# Not able to delete item in Cosmos DB using Azure SDK

Tags: database, azure-functions, nosql, azure-cosmosdb

I'm using Cosmos DB SDK in Javascript to find and delete an existing item in an Azure Function. Now initialising the Cosmos client seems to work, but actually finding an item doesn't for some reason.

Code to find/delete the item:

```
await container.item(id).delete();
```

The error:
[image]

I know the item exists with that given ID. Since it's present in the Cosmos DB.

This is the ID Cosmos DB is giving back saying it doesn't exist.
[image]

And this is the ID I see in the DB, so it's there.
[image]

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

EDIT:

I added the partition key value to the function:

```
await container.item(req.params.searchId, "/id").delete();
```

I believe /id is the partition key value:

[image]

But I'm still getting the same error back.

Comment: You are not including the partition key value.

Comment: Where can I find that value?

Comment: Look at the container properties and you should be able to find the attribute that is used as partition key. You will need to use the value of that attribute along with the id to delete a document.

Comment: Please see this as well: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/cosmos/container?view=azure-node-latest#@azure-cosmos-container-item.

Comment: I added the partition key I see in the cosmos DB container, but then I'm still getting the same error. I updated the question with the results

Comment: Your code should be `await container.item(id, new PartitionKey(id)).delete();`

Comment: Just read the item you want to delete into an item object then call delete on it. await item.delete();  Can find all our JS SDK samples here. https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/samples-nodejs

Comment: Aside from all the helpful advice already given: Please be sure to include properly formatted text in your questions, not images of text. See [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) for many reasons why this is really important.